# Why does this pregmatch pattern return true on a number input?

Tags: php, preg-match

I know this is very basic for some, but this got my head scratching. why does this pattern

```
/[!@#$%^&*()+|.*-<>\'`]/
```

return true on a number input i.e abcd123. tested it on [this tester](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester/)

Comment: `[*-<]` means ASCII characters 42 to 60. And numbers happen to be within that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the dash, which is otherwise interpreted as character range `\x2A-\x3E`:

```
/[!@#$%^&*()+|.*\-<>\'`]/
```

Comment: Yes, and the characters `*+,-./0123456789:;<` fall in that range

Comment: ah i get it. i'm not that great with preg_match must be the reason i missed it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `-` sign in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You have to backslash the "-", like this :

```
/[!@#$%^&()+|.\-<>\'`]/
```

I think you should backslash all special char too.